# How to automate Visual Studio's Code Metrics feature

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, code-metrics

I want to automate the process of gathering code metrics on a .NET solution. Is there any way of getting msbuild to run the Code Metrics feature included in VS2008 Development Edition?

I may end up using [SourceMonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html), but I would like to know if there is a way to use the VS code metrics engine from the command line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, Microsoft have provided us with [a way to automate the Visual Studio code metrics feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/camerons/archive/2011/01/28/code-metrics-from-the-command-line.aspx) using a new "[power tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=edd1dfb0-b9fe-4e90-b6a6-5ed6f6f6e615)".

Comment: I wanted to run my C++ Solution file (vs 2010) from command for code metric analysis.Will this work for C++ Project ?

Comment: The 'power tool' is missing

Answer (score 5):

This is how my company has automated FxCop using MSBuild:

```
<!-- The directory where FxCop is installed. -->
<FxCopDirectory>C:\Program Files\Microsoft FxCop 1.36</FxCopDirectory>

<!-- The FxCop console executable.. -->
<FxCopCmd>$(FxCopDirectory)\FxCopCmd</FxCopCmd>

<Target Name="CodeAnalysis>
<!-- Once to get XML for metrics. -->
<Exec Command="&quot;$(FxCopCmd)&quot; /p:&quot;$(BuildDirectory)\FxCop\RuleSet.FxCop&quot; /out:$(BuildResults)\FxCop.xml /summary /verbose /f:$(Binaries)\@(CodeAnalysis, ' /f:$(Binaries)\')" />

<!-- Once to report with the build results. -->
<Exec Command="&quot;$(FxCopCmd)&quot; /p:&quot;$(BuildDirectory)\FxCop\RuleSet.FxCop&quot; /out:$(BuildResults)\FxCop.html /summary /verbose /applyoutXsl:$(MSBuildTasks)\CodeAnalysisReport.xsl /f:$(Binaries)\@(CodeAnalysis, ' /f:$(Binaries)\')" />

<!-- Update the FxCop report so that it is fully expanded by default. -->
<FileUpdate Regex="&lt;body\s"
            ReplacementText="&lt;body onLoad=&quot;ExpandAll();&quot; "
            Files="$(BuildResults)\FxCop.html" />
</Target>
```

Then, you can write some C# code to consume the output file:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gather metrics for code analysis.
/// </summary>
private static void GatherCodeAnalysisMetrics()
{
    string file = @"$(BuildResults)\FxCop.xml";
    if (!File.Exists(file)) return;
    System.Xml.XmlDocument document = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    document.Load(file);
    System.Xml.XmlNodeList list = document.SelectNodes("//Message");
    codeAnalysisWarnings = list.Count;

    Console.WriteLine("Code analysis warnings: " + codeAnalysisWarnings);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jgwood - I believe he's referring to Code Metrics (cyclomatic complexity, etc.) and not FxCop.  I have been looking for a solution for this as well, as the FxCop rule for complexity has hardcoded threshholds.  It sounds like there's no command-line or API for the metrics in VS2008 yet (per [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2007/10/03/new-for-visual-studio-2008-code-metrics.aspx#5395389) on the Code Analysis Team Blog) - hopefully they'll release a powertool.

Have you looked at [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) for this?